# How do I get element from NSArray of NSDictionary

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary

This is NSLog of my NSArray

```
[{"id":16,"venueId":16,"street":"171 - 3401 Dufferin St","city":"Toronto","zipcode":"M6A 2T9","province":"ON","country":"Canada"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myarray objectAtIndex:i] 
//myarray is your array of dictionary
//if the array has just one element like in your example, i will be 0 

NSNumber *venueId = [dict objectForKey:@"venueId"];
```

Comment: It throws error -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: thanks Hetal. I used NSJSONSerialization to make sure data has NSArray type. I posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found solution

```
NSError *error;
    NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[venue objectForKey:@"address"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error] ;

    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
    //myarray is your array of dictionary

    NSString *street = [dict objectForKey:@"street"];
    NSLog(@"street: %@", street);
```

**Note: I used below code to check data type to make sure it returns valid kind of class.**

```
if ([[venue objectForKey:@"address"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"It is NSArray");
    } else if ([[venue objectForKey:@"address"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"It is NSString");
    }
```